# Debugging in Rest Api

Tags: magento-2.1, api, debug

I want to debug which api is called.Any tool is available for debugging in magento 2.1.12?Anybody help me.

Comment: Exactly where you wanted to debug ? - is there any custom functionality you have implemented or you wanted to debug in mobile app ?

Comment: I will  make one custom api for updateAddress with put method.It is working properly in my local server.But When i change in production,then it showing some error like SQLSTATE too many connections.Somebody tell me this error is generated by my api.So,i want to debug this api.

Comment: okay - i got your point , so here you need to post the code - exactly what you have tried so far and what is there in your file and how exactly you are calling url and all

Comment: give me your email id,i will send you code.